# Ruby detecting number of clusters in dataset

Tags: ruby, statistics

I have a survey app, and I am required to cluster the responses to detect for signs of coherence or decoherence.

I am using [AI4R](https://github.com/SergioFierens/ai4r/blob/master/examples/clusterers/clusterer_example.rb) and my code looks like the below (example code filched from AI4R)

```
# 5 Questions on a post training survey
questions = [   "The material covered was appropriate for someone with my level of knowledge of the subject.", 
                "The material was presented in a clear and logical fashion", 
                "There was sufficient time in the session to cover the material that was presented", 
                "The instructor was respectful of students", 
                "The instructor provided good examples"]

# Answers to each question go from 1 (bad) to 5 (excellent)
# The answers array has an element per survey complemented. 
# Each survey completed is in turn an array with the answer of each question.
answers = [ 
            [ 1, 2, 3, 2, 2],   # Answers of person 1
            [ 5, 5, 3, 2, 2],   # Answers of person 2
          ]

data_set = DataSet.new(:data_items => answers, :data_labels => questions)

# Let's group answers in 4 groups
clusterer = Diana.new.build(data_set, 4)
```

This in turn lets me create graphs like this (the survey has questions which are linked to themes/axes).

[image]

The problem is that right now you have to pick the number of clusters to pass into AI4R. How ccan I use Ruby to detect the number of clusters (this question boils over into the sstatistics discipline...).

---

### Enter the Elbow Method...

I saw on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set) that there is a technique called the elbow method (illustrative picture from Wikipedia),

[image]

which compares the number of clusters with the variance that they explain. This technique would be perfect for my needs, but I don't know how to implement it in Ruby. (I have done ANOVAs back in the day as an undergrad, so I get what they are about, but that is where it stops. I might need to cross-post on a stats forum as well).

Are there Ruby libraries that can assist with this that I have not stumbled upon yet, or alternately how would go about solving this problem using the Ruby ecosystem?